# AWS S3 boto3: Server-side filtering for top-level keys

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am developing a GUI for the analysts in my company to be able to browse a series of S3 buckets (and files therein named according to different hierarchies of keys) just as if they were working with any other hierarchical FS. The idea is that they can work without needing to know any details about how (or where) is the data actually stored.

I am aware of how S3 does not natively support folders and how can this be (to some extent) simulated by properly using key naming and delimiters. For my use case, let's suppose the content of my bucket is:

```
asset1/property1/fileA.txt
asset1/property2/fileB.txt
asset2/property1/fileA.txt
asset2/property2/fileB.txt
configX.txt
configY.txt
configZ.txt
```

I have so far written a simple GUI navigator that enables interactive navigation through the different levels of S3 keys as if they were folders (using the `CommonPrefixes` key of the dictionary returned by the s3 `client` or the `paginator`). The problem I have when I land in an example like the one above. Obviously, the `CommonPrefixes` is not going to return the file basenames under the requested key, but I also want to display them to the user (they are files contained in that *"folder"*!).

One thing that I have tried is for every "inspection" of a requested key level (when the user clicks on a list item (key substring) as if it was a folder) I retrieve the first, say, 1000 item basenames under the passed `prefix` and search for any file matching exactly the `{prefix}/{basename}` key. If any of the 1000 first files matches the criterion, it means that *"there are files contained directly in that very folder"*, so then I can use the `paginator` to query them all (eentually there are more than 1000 in total) and have their keys returned to me *"for displaying them in the folder"*.

The problem I have in the above situation is that the `paginator` will recursively inspect for all the contents with the passed key (logically), but, unlike in the above toy example, the 'asset' or 'property' *"folders"* can contain tens or hundreds of thousands files, thereby significantly slowing down the search "just" for being able to show the extra top-level 'config' files that share path with the asset *"folders"*.

I can filter the results myself to display at each level what it has to be displayed, thereby resembling the appearance of a hierarchical folder structure. Nevertheless, the loss of speed and interactiveness is massive, rendering the GUI solution for comfortable analyst experience somewhat pointless. I have been searching for a way to filter results server-side beyond the standard `prefix` and `delimiter` (e. g. passing a suffix or a regular expression), but I have been unable to find any solution that does not imply the (slow) full-key results retrieval and client-side filtering.

Is there any way to approach this that I am not seeing? What would be the correct way to go about this problem? Since I do not think my use-case is a very specific corner-case, apologies if this is a basic question that has already been solved. I have tried to find an answer, but chances are that I am unable to google.

Thanks very much in advance.

D.

P.S.: BTW I have read that `boto2` delivers the query results by levels, as I would expect them, but I am not certain that it wouldn't anyway query the whole bucket (which is what actually costs time)

Comment: I'm lost when you said "but I also want to display them to the user". Could you show us a screenshot of how you display them?

Comment: My understanding is if you want to show a tree view like the s3 web console, you always show users the exact next one level of the key. For example, top-level files and directories: `asset1/`, `asset2/`, `configX.txt`, `configY.txt`, `configZ.txt`. Then if the user clicked on `asset1/`, you show `property1` and `property2`. Every click goes one level deeper, no more.

Comment: @jellycsc your understanding is correct. Following the example, the problem is that the `CommonPrefixes` option of the s3 `client` as well as of the `paginator` will only return the folders `asset1` and `asset2`. In order to discover the files `configX.txt`, `configY.txt` and `configZ.txt` to display them at this key level (as you say), I have to recursively search all the content of the bucket, including the "contents" of the folders `asset1` and `asset2`, massively slowing down the speed. There seems to be no native option supported for searching only the next key level, so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) closely, besides `CommonPrefixes` being returned, there is also a `Contents` key which contains

> A list of metadata about each object returned.